# How can I disable multiline for autocomplete material-ui demo?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-select

Country select of 
[autocomplete demo at material-ui](https://material-ui.com/demos/autocomplete/)
uses react-select and material-ui controls,
shows multiline text, select control changes it's dimensions when country doesn't fit in one line.

I see this behaviour at CodeSandbox when I decrease width of web browser.

How can I modify demo so that country will always fit in one line,
select control will not change it's dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

`TextField` has props `multiline`, `rows` and `rowsMax` props that can be changed.

If that isn't what you need then you could add the following css to the text in the `TextField` so the text does not wrap:

```
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed this by mixing a few different things:

First create a class like so:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    closed: {
      flexWrap: "nowrap",
      overflowX: "hidden",
    },
    // Add a linear gradient behind the buttons and over the Chips (if applies)
    endAdornment: {
        background:
            "linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.6) 22%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 60%)",
        bottom: 0,
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        right: "0 !important",
        paddingRight: 9,
        paddingLeft: theme.spacing(2),
        top: 0,
},
  })
);
```

Then in your static function add this :

```
const onOpenChange = (open: boolean | null) => {
    setIsOpen(open);
};
const inputStyle = clsx({
    [classes.closed]: !isOpen, //only when isOpen === false
});
```

Finally on the Autocomplete component itself use:

```
classes={{ inputRoot: inputStyle, endAdornment: classes.endAdornment }}
onOpen={() => onOpenChange(true)}
onClose={() => onOpenChange(false)}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wondering how to make each option be displayed in just one line with ellipsis, you can do the follow:

```
<Autocomplete
...
getOptionLabel={(option: any) => `${option.label} (${option.code})`}
renderOption={(option) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <div style={{ textOverflow: 'ellipsis', overflow: "hidden", whiteSpace: "nowrap" }}>
            {option.label} ({option.code})
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
...
/>
```

For the Country Demo example, you can check what I did here: https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-with-ellipsis-i8hnw